# True or false under several conditions

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I want to check whether 
$$\max\bigl(0, x+\max(0, y+z-1)-1\bigr)=\max\bigl(0, z+\max(0, x+y-1)-1\bigr)$$
under restriction $x,y,z\in[0,1]$ but I don't know how to type it in WolframAlpha. For example this expression does not work:

```
  max(0, x+max(0, y+z-1)-1)=max(0, z+max(0, x+y-1)-1)  0<=x<= 1  0<=y<=1  0<=z<=1  true or false
```

Will be very grateful for help!

Comment: Do you want to know if this holds for all $(x,y,z)$, a particular triplet, or code that will check it for all triplets?

Comment: Stricktly for $x,y,z\in[0,1]$

Comment: I know that. That doesn't answer my question. What kind of answer do you want

Comment: I am do not exactly understand what triplet means. I just whant to check wheather this equality holds when my variables satisfy described condition.

Comment: A triplet is just a set of three variables. So you want to be able to check if it holds, for any set of three variables that meet your criterion.

Comment: Yes that is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To find out all of the solutions:**

It's a kinda magical fact that you can encode max and min into mathematical equations if you use absolute value.
$$\max(a,b)=\frac{(a-b)+|a-b|}{2}+b$$

With this, you can write an (albeit complicated) equation that wolfram alpha will recognize.

**To find out if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution for a particular set of values:**

If you want to know if $(1/2,1/2,1/2)$ is a solution to the equation, you can type in

```
max(0, 1/2+max(0, 1/2+1/2-1)-1)=max(0, 1/2+max(0, 1/2+1/2-1)-1)
```

Directly and it is able to calculate that on my computer.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer the question as well as for additional useful information!